# repeat a sequence from a lookup table across a set number of records oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

case:

the user is required to select a start and end date for a specific period and they are also required to select a sequence and where in the sequence they would like to start the sequence cycle (the sequence is stored in a lookup table...an example of a store sequence is shown in the example below under sequence lookup ).

```
user input parameters:
 start date : 01-jan-2021 
 end date : 14-jan-2021
 sequence_name : 1-5
 start sequence at : 4
```

after the user inputs the paramaters , the system will

list all dates between between 01-jan-2021 and 14-jan-2021 - shown below in the example then it will start to map the sequence to the dates starting with the sequence number inputted in this case its 4 (shown in example below)

when the system reaches the end of the sequence (in this case the end is 5) it will restart the sequence from 1 because that was the start of the sequence in the look up.

in the example image below it shows what the results should look like.

thank you for your help!

i prefer to write it in sql but if its not possible in sql then plsql is also fine.

[image: the example]

Comment: As you were asked before I think, please post text not images. Where is `sequence_name` translated to a list of values? Including relevant tables and sample data is always useful. It might also help to show how far you've got and what issues you are having.

Comment: sorry mate, i ust forgot how to do the covert to table in stack overflow...so i posted the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really explained how you get from your 'sequence name' to a range of values, so I'll assume you already that that part, and will work from a date range and a sequence range, which can be provided for simplicity as a CTE:

```
with input (start_date, end_date, start_seq, end_seq, start_at) as (
  select date '2021-01-01', date '2021-01-14', 1, 5, 4 from dual
)
select * from input
```

You tagged the question with Oracle 11g. If that is 11gR2 then you can use a recursive CTE to generate the result from that simulated input data:

```
with input (start_date, end_date, start_seq, end_seq, start_at) as (
  select date '2021-01-01', date '2021-01-14', 1, 5, 4 from dual
),
rcte (dt, seq, end_date, start_seq, end_seq) as (
  select start_date, start_at, end_date, start_seq, end_seq
  from input
  union all
  select dt + 1, case when seq = end_seq then start_seq else seq + 1 end,
    end_date, start_seq, end_seq
  from rcte
  where dt < end_date
)
select dt, seq
from rcte
order by dt;
```

The anchor member use the start date and start-at value, and keeps the other information needed later. The recursive member increments both, wrapping the seq value at the top of that range. Giving the result:

```
DT        | SEQ
:-------- | --:
01-JAN-21 |   4
02-JAN-21 |   5
03-JAN-21 |   1
04-JAN-21 |   2
05-JAN-21 |   3
06-JAN-21 |   4
07-JAN-21 |   5
08-JAN-21 |   1
09-JAN-21 |   2
10-JAN-21 |   3
11-JAN-21 |   4
12-JAN-21 |   5
13-JAN-21 |   1
14-JAN-21 |   2
```

On earlier versions, or just if you prefer it, you can use a hierarchical query, which looks shorter but I think it's a bit less intuitive:

```
with input (start_date, end_date, start_seq, end_seq, start_at) as (
  select date '2021-01-01', date '2021-01-14', 1, 5, 4 from dual
)
select start_date + level - 1 as dt,
  mod(level - 1 + start_at - start_seq, end_seq - start_seq + 1) + start_seq as seq
from input
connect by level <= end_date - start_date + 1
order by dt;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=65e7c1d418d58c92135f2aca8bdcbdf7) showing both approaches.

And a second [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=28e6de40e574e8a5844e428789ca5ab0) showing a different sequence range and starting point.

Comment: the sequence name was actually 'seq1-5' as the name just for refernce sake

Comment: this is enough for me to expand upon the concepts thanks!!!! great help!